# Convert RGB hexadecimal to 3d matrix in R

Tags: r, image, raster

I have an RGB image that any cell is a characteristic value like "#FFFFFF".
I would like to convert this format to a 3D matrix and use that for image processing and unfortunately I don't now how do that.

Comment: Please check `?col2rgb`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i want do rgb2col, the command that not exit

Comment: Why do you want `rgb2col`?

Comment: I need values as number to compute on image. For this time I need to show one image above other image with transparency and the only way I considered is sum two image like resultim=(0.5*im1+0.5*img2)

Comment: You asked to transform hexadecimal into RGB. `col2rgb` does that. col2rgb("#FFFFFF") gives (255, 255, 255).

Comment: I asked hexadecimal to 3d matrix. I know that col2rgb(255,255,255) gives ('#FFFFFF'). I need do inverse

Comment: It is what I told you. You have to work a little to create a 3d matrix from `col2rgb`.

Comment: Thanks my freind. Do i underestand that you say "No straight way is exit"

Comment: There is a way. Use `col2rgb` and `array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use color "#8A2BE2":

```
# Create a 4x4 matrix with the same color
hex <- matrix(rep("#8A2BE2", 16), 4, 4)
hex
#      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     
# [1,] "#8A2BE2" "#8A2BE2" "#8A2BE2" "#8A2BE2"
# [2,] "#8A2BE2" "#8A2BE2" "#8A2BE2" "#8A2BE2"
# [3,] "#8A2BE2" "#8A2BE2" "#8A2BE2" "#8A2BE2"
# [4,] "#8A2BE2" "#8A2BE2" "#8A2BE2" "#8A2BE2"

rgbs <- col2rgb(hex)
# First 5 columns
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# red    138  138  138  138  138
# green   43   43   43   43   43
# blue   226  226  226  226  226

rgbs <- array(t(rgbs), c(4,4,3))
dim(rgbs)
# we get a 4x4x3 array
# [1] 4 4 3

rgbs[1:2,1:2,]
# First 2 lines and first 2 columns
# , , 1
# 
#     [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  138  138
# [2,]  138  138
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   43   43
# [2,]   43   43
# 
# , , 3
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  226  226
# [2,]  226  226
```